# In c, what are the rules governing how compilers merge the same strings into the executable

Tags: c, compiler-construction

I am trying to find what the rules are for c and c++ compilers putting strings into the data section of executables and don't know where to look. I would like to know if the address of all of the following are guaranteed to be the same in c/c++ by the spec:

```
char * test1 = "hello";
const char * test2 = "hello";
static char * test3 = "hello";
static const char * test4 = "hello";
extern const char * test5; // Defined in another compilation unit as "hello"
extern const char * test6; // Defined in another shared object as "hello"
```

Testing on windows, they are all the same. However I do not know if they would be on all operating systems.

Comment: This can't be part of the standard, forget about it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*I would like to know if the address of all of the following are guaranteed to be the same in c/c++ by the spec*

String literals are allowed to be the same object but are not required to.

C++ says:

> (C++11, 2.14.5p12) "Whether all string literals are distinct (that is, are stored in nonoverlapping objects) is implementation-defined. The effect of attempting to modify a string literal is undefined."

C says:

> (C11, 6.5.2.5p7) "String literals, and compound literals with const-qualified types, need not designate distinct objects.101) This allows implementations to share storage for string literals and constant compound literals with the same or overlapping representations."

And C99 Rationale says:

> "This specification allows implementations to share copies of strings with identical text, to place string literals in read-only memory, and to perform certain optimizations"

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, this has nothing to do with the operating system. It depends solely on the implementation, i.e on the compiler.

Secondly, the only "guarantees" you can hope for in this case will come from the compiler documentation. The formal rules of the language neither guarantee them to be the same, nor guarantee them to be different. (The latter applies to both C and C++.)

Thirdly, some compilers have such bizarre options like "make string literals modifiable". This usually implies that each literal is allocated in a unique region of storage and has unique address.

Comment: The compiler alone is not the implementation. The operating system is part of a C implementation. A dynamic loader could choose to consolidate constant sections from separate dynamic libraries, if the object format contained sufficient information.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil: No. A compiler is free to rely on OS properties, if it so desires. But at the same time it is free to deliberately override/neutralize/sabotage these properties, if their behavior does not match the compiler's intent. There's no limit to the thickness of the hardware/OS abstraction layer a compiler can implement. Compilers don't do it out of pure efficiency considerations, not because they are somehow prohibited from dong that.

Comment: If the compiler avoids the system loader and does everything itself, then the result has little to do with the operating system (“nothing to do with the operating system” remains incorrect, as there still must be initial loading of some code, program execution, and minimal system services). Certainly this is rare, and regular C implementations use the normal system services. The C implementation is everything that contributes to program translation and execution, not just the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

They can all be the same. Even `x` and `y` in the following can be the same. `z` can overlap with `y`

```
const char *x = "hello";
const char *y = "hello\0folks";
const char *z = "folks";
```

Answer (score 0):

In C, I believe the only guarantee about a string literal is that it will evaluate to a pointer to a readable area of memory that will, assuming a program does not engage in Undefined Behavior, always contain the indicated characters followed by a zero byte.  The compiler and linker are allowed to work together in any fashion they see fit to make that happen.  While I don't know of any compiler/linker systems that do this, it would be perfectly legitimate for a compiler to put each string literal in its own constant section, and for a linker to place such sections in reverse order of length, and check before placing each one whether the appropriate sequence of bytes had already been placed somewhere.  Note that the sequence of bytes wouldn't even have to be a string literal or defined constant; if the linker is trying to place the string `"Hi!"` and it notices that machine code contains the sequence of bytes [0x48, 0x69, 0x21, 0x00], the literal could evaluate to a pointer to the first of those.

Note that writing to the memory pointed to by a string literal is Undefined Behavior.  On various system a write may trap, do nothing, or affect only the literal written, but it could also have totally unpredictable consequences [e.g. if the literal evaluated to a pointer into some machine code].